# Angular 6 visual studio loading shows up only

Tags: visual-studio-2017, angular6

I have created a angular 6 with Visual studio 2017 community edition following this Url.
http://www.learnonlineasp.net/2017/12/learn-angular-5-from-scratch-without-angular-cli.html
I have done exactly same steps and When I run it I get a laoding.... only.
TS creates .js files but I am not getting angular variables displayed on page.

Comment: could you provide further information? Are you getting any console error?

Comment: no error at all. it compiles all fine. ctrl+F5 brings the site and only <my-app>Loading...</my-app> on the index page comes up.

Comment: I am using angular 6.0.3 vs angular 5.0.1 used in example

Comment: I meant, any errors in whichever browser you're using. If you're using Chrome, open up the DevTools and check the "Console" tab. See what you get there

Comment: 2Reflect.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:58440/Scripts/App/main:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Index:20 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:58440/Scripts/App/main
  Loading ../../Scripts/App/main
    at fetch.js:37
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

Answer (score 0):

@Metehanson, please check where that main.js file resides, I see in the tutorial they say to load the main.js file like this:

```
System.import('dist/main.js').catch(function (err) {
     console.error(err);
});
```

But then you're attempting to get it under "../../Scripts/App/main", make sure that location exists.

The main.js under the dist directory will be generated after running `npm build`, so make sure you run this command before `npm run`